# Expression.Coalesce in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

Is it possible to use the `Expression.Coalesce` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302730.aspx) in Linq to Entities?
How? Any example available?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `??` operator in a linq to entities query like this:

```
var query = from x in context.Table
            select x.Property1 ?? "Test";
```

The `Expression.Coalesce` method is used when you want to construct the query dynamically.

Comment: And I want to construct it dynamically. The ?? operator doesn't work with different data types

Comment: The `??` operator works with Nullable data types. That's its purpose. If you're trying to build a dynamic Expression tree, you probably won't be using it anyway.

Comment: This answer doesn't work me in VS2017 + SQL 2017. CASE statement is always generated. Is there any precondition?